# How to send HTML form data as email in Rails? (without using a gem)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am using rails for the first time to develop a web application.

On my `index.html.erb` I have an html contact form which looks like this.

```
<form  method="post" name="frmContentDownload"><!-- /. form handling starts here-->

      <div><label for="FirstName1">First Name</label><input class="form-control" name="FirstName1" type="text" value="" /></div>
      <div><label for="LastName1">Last Name</label><input class="form-control" name="LastName1" type="text" value="" /></div>
      <div><label for="emailAddress">Email</label><input class="form-control" name="emailAddress" type="text" value="" /></div>
      <div><label for="PhoneNumber">Phone</label><input class="form-control" name="PhoneNumber" type="text" value="" /></div>
      <div><label for="Title1">Title</label><input class="form-control" name="Title1" type="text" value="" /></div>
      <div><label for="StateProvince1">State or Province</label><select class="form-control" name="StateProvince1">
        <option class="placeholder" value="" disabled selected>COUNTRY &#8609;</option>
        <option value="CA">Canada</option>
        <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="US">United States</option>
      </select></div>

        <div><label for="comments">Comments</label><input class="form-control" name="comments" type="text" value="" /></div>

        <div><input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" value="Contact Us" /></div>
</form>
```

I am trying to understand how I can wire this up so that the contact information is sent to my email. I understand there are ruby gems available to do this, but I am happy with the aesthetics of the form and do not want to use a gem for form handling.

The heroku version is [here](https://gastromend.herokuapp.com)

Any steering would be appreciated.

Comment: Rails comes with [Action Mailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html). Just create a simple mailer and call it from the controller which processes your form.

Comment: thanks for the steering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you need to install `smtp` server for sending email, Heroku has an add-on for [`Sendgrid`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid#ruby) email install and configure this.

Then run below command for creating email class and template

```
rails generate mailer ContactMailer
```

it will generate like below

```
create  app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb
create  app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
invoke  erb
create    app/views/contact_mailer
create    app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb
create    app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb
invoke  test_unit
create    test/mailers/contact_mailer_test.rb
create    test/mailers/previews/contact_mailer_preview.rb
```

You can follow this for basic [Rails Mailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails), also here is a [`full tutorial`](https://matharvard.ca/posts/2014/dec/31/contact-form-in-rails-4/) for sending an email with a contact form and mail folders structure how mail classes and templates work together.

Comment: thanks, how do I then refactor my form to synch this

Comment: @wengtee, updated the answer see this tutorial URL for how to do this https://matharvard.ca/posts/2014/dec/31/contact-form-in-rails-4/

Comment: Note that the tutorial is from 2014, some things may have changed.

Comment: anything particular that may have changed, that I should be aware of especially

Comment: @Stefan, Thanks for this, this was just an example that how mail folders structured, no more than that, actual mail flavor is described Rails Guides which I have mentioned in my answer like this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails

Comment: yes but does this method not rely on me having to refactor my form with some sort of erb. I want to keep my existing HTML form

Comment: @fool-dev it was not meant as an offence, I just wanted to point out that it may be outdated :-)

Comment: @Stefan Great! and Thanks :)